# Как получить выбранный объект из списка на странице jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Форма на странице jsf

```
 <h:form id="position_">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.position}"  converter="org.jboss.seam.faces.conversion.ObjectConverter" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{positionBean.positionList}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.title}" itemValue="#{c.id}"  />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Save Position" action="#{personBean.addPositionToPerson(c.id)}"  />
    </h:form>
```

Как собственное получить в данный метод значение id

```
 public String addPositionToPerson(long id) {
    person = personServiceNew.findById(id);
    position = positionService.findPositionById(id);
    person.setPosition(position);
    person = personServiceNew.merge(person);
    return "viewPersonList.xhtml";
}
```

в данной строке position = positionService.findPositionById(id); все время вылетает NullPointer. Бин сессионный.

Comment: Вылетает потому, что `positionService` равен `null`. Он внедряется в этот бин?

Comment: конечно @EJB
    private PositionService positionService;
    private Position position = new Position();

Comment: А сам бин какой аннотацией помечен? Сервер какой?

Comment: Named, @SessionScoped ,WildFly

Comment: @Oleg найдите, что у вас null с помощью отладчика.

Comment: private Position position = new Position(); тут сначала null, а потом и в  
          position = positionService.findPositionById(id);

Comment: position тут принимающая сторона, она не может выкидывать NPE

Comment: может тут и собака зарыта, тк у person видно хеш объекта, а position все время null.

Comment: выдает нп именно эта строка  position = positionService.findPositionById(id); а в отладчике position просто со значением null

Comment: @Oleg NPE выбрасывается, когда код пытается вызвать какой либо метод у объекта null, т.к. кодом обладаете только вы, то через отладчик найдите где выбрасывается NPE, кто его выбрасывает, какой объект это делает и почему он null.

Comment: @Oleg Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Answer (score 0):

Сокращение `c` действует только области видимости `f:selectItems` но никак не в кнопке. Тем более, что выбранное значение записывается в `#{personBean.position}`. Вам только нужно отправить данные формы на сервер как показано ниже.

```
<h:form id="position_">
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.position}"  converter="org.jboss.seam.faces.conversion.ObjectConverter" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{positionBean.positionList}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.title}" itemValue="#{c.id}"  />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <h:commandButton value="Save Position" action="#{personBean.addPositionToPerson()}" execute="@form" render="@this"/>
</h:form>
```

И получить в методе через связанное свойство:

```
public String addPositionToPerson() {
    Long id = position.getId();
    person = personServiceNew.findById(id);
    position = positionService.findPositionById(id);
    person.setPosition(position);
    person = personServiceNew.merge(person);
    return "viewPersonList.xhtml";
}
```